# How do I create a pull request against an upstream base that is the difference between two branches in my forked repo?

Tags: git, github

I forked a repo on GitHub, cloned it locally, made changes, committed them locally and pushed them back to my github repo.  I then opened a pull request against upstream for the changes.  (That pull request is still outstanding.)

Then I created locally created a branch, made some more changes in it, committed them and pushed the new branch to github.

How do I open a pull request against the upstream repo for just the changes in my branch?

I tried creating a pull request naïvely, with base fork == upstream, base branch == master, head fork == my repo, head branch == the new feature branch I created, but the list of diffs includes not only the new changes but all the changes in the still-outstanding pull request I made previously.

I then tried creating a pull request with base fork == my repo, base branch == master, head fork == my repo, head branch == feature branch.  It shows exactly the desired diff, but to be applied to my master, not the upstream master.

How do I create a pull request for just the diffs between my master and feature branches, but to be applied to the upstream master?  Or do I have to wait for the first pull request to be accepted before this is possible?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that your problem is that the new branch was branched from the old branch.

You could go back to the original branch (master, development?) and create a new branch and then cherry pick or reapply the changes. The pull request for the new branch should only contain the 'new' changes.

Answer (score 1):

You've all the changes in `new-branch` because you've created this branch from `previous branch` not from `master`.

```
$ git log                        # copy commit-sh that have your new changes

$ git checkout master
$ git checkout -b <branch-1>     # checkout a new branch 'branch-1' that has no changes
$ git cherry-pick <commit-sha>   # take the changes into 'branch-1'
$ git push origin HEAD           # push the changes to remote branch-1
```

Then create a new pull request from your `branch-1`.